# Is every subset of a Borel set Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that every subset of a Borel set is Lebesgue measurable? Why?

Comment: No. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set, and not every subset of it is measurable. However, it is true that every subset of a Borel set which has measure zero is Leb. measurable.

Comment: @Shalop: Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subset of $\mathbb R$ is a subset of a Borel set (namely $\mathbb R$).  So any non-Lebesgue measurable set of reals is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since $[0,1]$ is Borel and you can create a Vitali set on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect this?  The interval (0,1) is Borel, but not all of its subsets are Lebesgue-measurable (assuming Axiom of Choice).

Comment: I'm reading a book and thinking something that is related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not true...As one can construct a non-measurable set in open interval (0,1)...